Getting Error "The required anti forgery form field __RequestVerificationToken is not present" on Saml2PostBinding Logout
My organization requires me to protect my Logout (SAML 2.0 code) method with the ValidateAntiForgeryToken attribute. I am using the @Html.AntiForgeryToken() in my View to send the verification token and cookie to the Logout method for validation, however once the Logout method is executed, I am getting the error:
The required anti forgery form field __RequestVerificationToken is not present.
I tried injecting the hidden field __RequestVerificationToken into the HTML response generated by Saml2PostBinding. It did not work, still getting the same error.
Is there any support for Anti forgery token in SAML 2.0?
PS - Apologies I cannot post the code as the tool simply is not allowing me. Hope the above info suffices. Please get back if anything further needed from me.

It is possible to protect the initiating login and logout method with anti forgery tokens, but not the subsequently SAML 2.0 HTTP GET ant POST sequence.
